# Paypal and Magento IPN issue

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

We had a eCheck Order for the first time magento 1.7.0.2 paypal express..I have never had any issue with paypal at all...I contacted paypal : They checked the transaction id in my ipn history and it seems that there was already an IPN being sent for that particular transaction.  and it was sent successfully to our url. It seems that Magento isnt updating the transaction status once it receives the IPN.

What can I do I need to ship this order out today and the status is still Payment Review? We waited over a week for the eCheck to clear and it DID clear in paypals end but in MAGENTO it still is Payment Review.

Please help!